# Flash timeline elapsed time calculation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am doing an animation and it has around 5000 frames and the frame rate is 24. I want to calculate the elapsed time in seconds.

Consider I navigated to 1000 th frame.  Now what was the elapsed time?

```
 var fps:Number = 24;
 var totolF:Number = 5000; 
 var sec:Number = 5000/24;
 var cF:Number = 1000;
 var elapsedTime:Number = ???
```

Comment: var fps:Number = 24;
var totolF:Number = 5000;
var sec:Number = 5000/24;
var cF:Number = 1000;

var elapsedTime:Number = cF * sec;  ???

Comment: Why not just do: `var time:Number = 1000 / 24`? your have 24 **frames per second** and you have 1000 **frames**, so a simple division will give you the elapsed time in seconds.

Comment: Please add your code to the question with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

First way:

```
var fps:Number = 24;
var totolF:Number = 5000; 
var sec:Number = 5000/24;
var cF:Number = 1000;

var elapsedTime:Number = Math.floor(1/24 *currentFrame);
```

Second way(more accurate but if you **pause** your movie, elapsed time won't pause):

```
var fps:Number = 24;
var totolF:Number = 5000; 
var sec:Number = 5000/24;
var cF:Number = 1000;

var elapsedTime:Number =Math.floor(getTimer()/1000);
```

I think better to use first one.

Hopes this post helps.☻